# Matching integer at one string Lex

Tags: lex

Need to match integer type but it must be only separated integer. Example:

```
INTEGER (-?[0-9]+)
NOTENDLINE  [^$]
%%
{INTEGER}/{NOTENDLINE}     {}
%%
```

If I enter string like "23test", it must be wrong and no integer matched. But my solution don't working as needed. I don't know, what I need in NOTENDLINE.

Comment: You can't negate the end of line marker ($) by using the negated character class syntax ([^]).  You write "must be only separated integer," but I don't understand your rule: What characters can and cannot follow your integer string?

Comment: string may be like "test 123test ", for example. There's many tokens, but i need parse separate integers. In "test 123 " result integer 123, in example before no integers. String consists of any characters, but for accepting, integer, if it there, must be separated at least by spaces or endlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match an integer but only if it is followed by whitespace, do so directly:

```
-?[[:digit:]]+/[[:space:]]
```

That will fail if the integer is at the very end of the file without a newline, but text files are not supposed to end with anything other than a newline character. You can, however, do the following:

```
-?[[:digit:]]+/[[:space:]]    { /* Handle an integer */ }
-?[[:digit:]]+/.              { /* Handle the error */ }
-?[[:digit:]]+                { /* Handle an integer; this one must be at EOF */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?  It relies on the fact that the lexer will find the longest matched rule, but if two are equal, the first rule will be used.

```
%option noyywrap
DIGIT   [0-9]
OTHER   [a-z0-9]*
%%
{DIGIT}+        printf( "Integer: %s (%d)\n", yytext, atoi( yytext ) );
{OTHER}         printf( "Other: %s\n", yytext );
[ \t\n]+        /* eat up whitespace */
%%
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
        ++argv, --argc;  /* skip over program name */
        if ( argc > 0 )
                yyin = fopen( argv[0], "r" );
        else
                yyin = stdin;
        yylex();
}
```

Sample Input (file):

```
test
test123
123
123test
```

Sample Ouput:

```
Other: test
Other: test123
Integer: 123 (123)
Other: 123test
```